# Creating a test database on a mac

Tags: java, sql, eclipse, macos

I am currently running Eclipse on a Mac running OSX and I am creating a java program that needs to read and write to a database. However, I do not currently have access to the SQL database that I am going to use. Is there anyway a can make a temporary test SQL database to test my code?

Comment: You usually use an in-memory one such as H2.

Comment: Or install one via homebrew/macports. But H2 first option to get up and running as @chrylis say. I have a spring boot rest-api example using postgresql at https://github.com/kometen/SpringBootWorldCities you can clone if you wish.

Answer (score 0):

¿is this link useful for you? 
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/downloads/sqldev-install-mac-1969675.html

Comment: No I cant use the oracle SQL developer because I dont have an actual database to connect it to. I was wondering if the was something I could install that would act as a database so I can test my java code against

Comment: or maybe there is a Eclsipe tool or extension I can use?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the best/easiest way to solve this problem was to download a  PostgreSQL database, then use a JDBC to get the data into Eclipse